# Outlook 365 desktop - Unread Mail folder - mark selected emails as read and some disappear

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, desktop

Viewing emails listed in Unread Mail, I select a few similar emails and mark as read with Ctrl+Q. Some of those emails then disappear from this view. They're still there in the inbox, etc. but disappear from this view. Mighty annoying.

Have scoured the Advanced View settings for this folder but can't see anything obviously related/causing this problem.

Any ideas appreciated.

Using Microsoft Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2302) - it's Outlook desktop app for M365.

---

Example:

- Two emails unread - similar subject:
  [image: outlook two unread]
- Select both of the emails, Ctrl+Q to mark as read, and then one email unhelpfully disappears:
  [image: outlook just one email now]

Comment: Does closing and opening Outlook fix the problem?

Comment: @harrymc No. It is consistent.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's technically no such thing as an "Unread" folder. It's a view of your unread email which is why those unread items are in both that view and in your actual Inbox. Essentially there's a rule on that view that says "show me all email items that have a state of "Unread".

So yes, once you mark an email as Read it will disappear from that view, because it's no longer "Unread". That's the entire point of that view. The expected use case is to be able to work through the emails you've not yet read, and clear out from the list those that you have.

If you read an email but don't want to deal with it until later, so want it to remain in that view, can you always mark it as unread again. Either clicking the Unread button in Outlook, or pressing CTRL-U.

If you want to view both read and unread email, you want to go direct to your Inbox (or relevant folder) and view it from there, where both are shown.

Comment: Yes, I understand how the Unread Mail view works. What I'm pointing out is that marking a few selected emails as read doesn't make *all* of those selected disappear - only some.